# How do I execute an asynchronous startup on a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I'm pretty behind the curve with async-await, so this is probably a "duh" question.

I am working on what is supposed to be a very minimal UI application that runs from the system tray using the [WPF NotifyIcon](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon#context_menus) library.

The application should run very simply (for the user) in the following fashion:

- The program starts
- If necessary, there is a splash screen telling the user the program is running and prompting them to log in (if they haven't yet done so in a previous iteration).
- The WPF NotifyIcon appears in the system tray.
- Asynchronous execution begins

The problem into which I am running is the "Asynchronous execution begins" part. All of what happens up until then works fine, but when the program starts trying to "run", the UI locks up (by which I mean, users can click like insane people on the Tray Icon and the context menu refuses to appear).

This lockup occurs for an an unacceptably long period of time.

This is the startup code:

```
private async void AppStartup( object sender, StartupEventArgs e ) {
    this.TRSIcon = this.FindResource( "TRSIcon" ) as TaskbarIcon;
    if ( Settings.Default.DoUpgrade ) { //Upgrade if necessary.
        Settings.Default.Upgrade( );
        Settings.Default.DoUpgrade = false;
        Settings.Default.Save( );
    }

    if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( Settings.Default.Username ) || string.IsNullOrEmpty( Settings.Default.Password ) ) {
        new Help( ).ShowDialog( );
        Tuple<string, string> UP;
        if ( ( UP = Login.Instance.GetUserPassword( ) ) != null ) {
            Settings.Default.Username = UP.Item1;
            Settings.Default.Password = UP.Item2;
            Settings.Default.Save( );
        } else
            return;
    }
    await this.Start( ); //<-----This is where the meat of the program runs and it hangs the UI until it finishes.
    return; //<-----This is just so that I have a break point to see that await this.Start is blocking (I have to do it like that right? or do I?)
}
```

This is the `Resources.xaml`:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Tools="clr-namespace:WPFTools.TaskbarNotification;assembly=WPFTools"
    xmlns:TR="clr-namespace:TriviaRetriever">
    <ContextMenu x:Key="TSRInterfaceMenu" x:Shared="false">
        <MenuItem Header="Login" Command="{Binding cmdLogin}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Get My Trivia" Command="{Binding cmdDownload}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Register" Command="{Binding cmdRegister}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Lost Password" Command="{Binding cmdLostPassword}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="About" Command="{Binding cmdAbout}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Log Out" Command="{Binding cmdLogout}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Exit" Command="{Binding cmdExit}"/>
    </ContextMenu>

    <Tools:TaskbarIcon
        x:Key="TRSIcon"
        MenuActivation="LeftOrDoubleClick"
        IconSource="/TRIcon.ico"
        DoubleClickCommand="{Binding cmdAbout}"
        ContextMenu="{StaticResource TSRInterfaceMenu}">
        <Tools:TaskbarIcon.DataContext>
            <TR:TRSIViewModel/>
        </Tools:TaskbarIcon.DataContext>
    </Tools:TaskbarIcon>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This is the MVVM for the context menu commands:

```
public class TRSIViewModel {
    public ICommand cmdLogin {
        get {
            return new DelegateCommand {
                fncCanExecute = ( ) => ( Application.Current as App ).Core == null,
                actCommand = async ( ) => {
                    Tuple<string, string> LoginPassword = Login.Instance.GetUserPassword( );
                    if ( LoginPassword != null ) {
                        Settings.Default.Username = LoginPassword.Item1;
                        Settings.Default.Password = LoginPassword.Item2;
                        Settings.Default.Save( );
                        await ( Application.Current as App ).Start( );
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public ICommand cmdLogout {
        get {
            return new DelegateCommand {
                fncCanExecute = ( ) => ( Application.Current as App ).Core != null,
                actCommand = ( ) => {
                    ( Application.Current as App ).Core.Terminate( );
                    ( Application.Current as App ).Core = null;
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public ICommand cmdRegister {
        get {
            return new DelegateCommand {
                fncCanExecute = ( ) => true,
                actCommand = ( ) => Process.Start( @"https://www.digigames.com/weekly_subscriptions/index.php" )
            };
        }
    }

    public ICommand cmdLostPassword {
        get {
            return new DelegateCommand {
                fncCanExecute = ( ) => true,
                actCommand = ( ) => Process.Start( @"https://www.digigames.com/weekly_subscriptions/lost_password.php" )
            };
        }
    }

    public ICommand cmdAbout {
        get {
            return new DelegateCommand {
                fncCanExecute = ( ) => true,
                actCommand = ( ) => ( Application.Current as App ).TRSIcon.ShowCustomBalloon( new About( ), PopupAnimation.Slide, 5000 )
            };
        }
    }

    public ICommand cmdExit {
        get {
            return new DelegateCommand {
                fncCanExecute = ( ) => true,
                actCommand = ( ) => {
                    if ( ( Application.Current as App ).Core != null )
                        ( Application.Current as App ).Core.Terminate( );
                    Application.Current.Shutdown( 0 );
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public ICommand cmdDownload {
        get {
            return new DelegateCommand {
                fncCanExecute = ( ) => ( Application.Current as App ).Core != null,
                actCommand = async ( ) => await ( Application.Current as App ).Core.DownloadTrivia( true )
            };
        }
    }

    public class DelegateCommand : ICommand {

        public Action actCommand { get; set; }
        public Func<bool> fncCanExecute { get; set; }

        public bool CanExecute( object parameter ) {
            return this.fncCanExecute != null && this.fncCanExecute( );
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute( object parameter ) { this.actCommand( ); }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You should be returning a `Task`, you want to avoid using `async void` as the return type. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: @Will: The problem is probably within the `Start` method, which is not shown. Please simplify to a minimal, reproducible example - identify the asynchronous code that is executing synchronously and just ask about that.

Comment: @RonBeyer
Returning a task is valid except, or so I heard, when dealing with event handlers, which the Startup method is.

Comment: @StephenCleary
I'm in the middle of going through and cleaning up the entire thing. I've read a bit of your blog posts so I want to follow what you outlined, and given what I've learned working on another project before this one, there's a bit that needs to be done here...

Comment: related?: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/november/asynchronous-programming-async-from-the-start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is all about your `Start` method.

But first things first. Your breakpoint is not doing what you expect it to do. It breaks once the `Start` method actually finished and the remaining function is executed and not once the UI thread is freed up again. You have to understand that the UI thread is free to run again once the execution leaves the UI synchronization in the `Start` function.

A good way to find out how long it takes until the method actually frees the execution is to wait for it to return the `Task` object.

```
var pendingTask = this.Start();
Debugger.Break();
await pendingTask;
```

The `Task` object returns once the `Start` method hits a function that executes asynchronously internally. The `await` returns once the `pendingTask` actually finished.

In your case I think the times will be similar because the `Start` method isn't sending sufficient work into the background.

There are a couple of ways to go about that. If your `Start` method isn't interacting with the UI, you are fine. You just send the entire method into the background and be done with it. This works as simple as:

```
await Task.Run(() => this.Start());
```

This sends the task into a thread of the ThreadPool and frees the UI again right away. The `Task.Run` method has a overload that automatically unwraps the inner `Task` that is returned by the `Start` method.

If your method interacts with the UI, you have to alter the method internally. Look for the parts inside the method that take a long time and do not interact with the UI and wrap them into calls of the `Task.Run` method as shown above.

Every `await` will establish the `SynchronizationContext` that was present before again. So every `await` in the thread that is able to alter the UI will ensure that the continuation is executed in this very same thread too.

So things like this work without problem:

```
someLabel.Label = "Working…";
await Task.Run(() => DoManyThings());
someLabel.Label = "Done! :D"
```

I hope that helps. I can't give you more hints without knowing what your `Start` method does. But I hope that answer sets you on the right track.

*My usual disclaimer: I normally use VB.net and so my C# code may be flawed in matters of the syntax. If you notice any error, feels free to edit it or tell me what is wrong.*

Comment: You were right; the bulk of the issue was in the start method, but the biggest issue was creating a UI object before running all the behind stuff when it was better to just create it while things were running Asynchronously using a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke call to do so... Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a new `Thread` and run it off that.

```
   private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        //Some login logic
        if(loggedIn) //Or however you do it
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                this.RunWhateverMethodWillDoABunchOfStuff()
            });
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
        }
```

Depending on the exact program and what you want, you could also use a `BackgroundWorker`, which is a nice ansync way to run backgroun operations while recieving progress updates from the backgrund thread, allowing you to update something like a loading bar or something like that. If you want more info on that let me know

EDIT: sorry I did not notice you were running an ansync method. I would avoid that all together and simply run it in a normal method and just a thread (assuming you dont need progress updates or alerts for when its done, otherwise use backgroundworker). I feel you are over complicating this. Editing my code to reflect this

EDIT 2: Here is an example of the `BackgroundWorker` approach for anyone who cares

```
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += BwOnDoWork;
        bw.ProgressChanged += BwOnProgressChanged;
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += BwOnRunWorkerCompleted;
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

        //This line here is what starts the asynchronous work
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();



    private void BwOnRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs runWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    {
         //Do whatever you want to do when it is done with its asynchronous task
         //for example
         Label.Content = "Yay, Were done doing whatever it was that we were doing!!!!"
    }

    private void BwOnProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Here is where we can send progress reports to the UI, like updating a loading bar
        MyProgressBar.EditValue = e.ProgressPercentage;

    }

    private void BwOnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
    {
        //This is where we will put anything we want to be ran asynchronously
        this.RunWhateverMethodWillDoABunchOfStuff()
    }
```

Comment: The big issue is that there is a lot of database and FTP action going on behind the scenes. The UI should be fluid, and yes, there are some notifications that go on. I would use a background worker but they accomplish the same thing; just async is... more clean (I think?) and I'm really trying to familiarize myself with it. It's over two years old, going on 3, and I've only heard about it in the past six months...

Comment: @Will from everything I know, BackgroundWorker is the way to go when it comes to UI notifications during your asynchronous stuff. they also have nice built in functionality, and I personally find them very easy to work with. I have no experience with `async` though, so I cant weigh in on that unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for your help; I've worked with BGW before but to switch from async to BGW (given how far along the application is) would be throwing away work in a needless fashion, I feel.

Comment: @Will fair enough. I added some code for background worker example in case any passer bys are interested in it