# WPF: Execute some code asynchronously in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, asynchronous, delegates

I have a MVVM WPF app. I have a window, let's say "LvWindow", with a listview that is loaded from data comming from a database. From main window "MainWindow", I have a menu, which has some options. When I select the option to access "LvWindow", it is open. Then from ViewModel, in the constructor I have a call to a database from which I request some data that then I load into the listview.

My goal is to make the process to request data from database and then load it in the listview asynchronous. I want this in order to not block the whole app, I mean, during this window is loaded, user can go to the main window menu and select to open another type of window. Windows are open in tabs.

While the process of requesting data from database and being loaded into listview in window "LvWindow", I show a splash saying "Loading" on it(in fact this is a rectangle with zindex set to a higher number to avoid user can interact with listview until it is completely loaded). This splash will be closed when the listview is loaded with the data comming from database.

So to make the process asynchronous, I know in winforms it can be done with delegates by using beginInvoke, endInvoke and callbacks methods, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/2e08f6yc(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also, another possibility is to use a background worker, like posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414563/how-do-i-execute-an-asynchronous-startup-on-a-wpf-application).

So in WPF which is the best way to do it? using delegates as winforms or background workers?

**ATTEMPT #1**:
I have tried XANIMAX solution as this:

```
public class TestViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private static Dispatcher _dispatcher;
    public ObservableCollection<UserData> lstUsers

    public ObservableCollection<UserData> LstUsers
    {
        get
        {
            return this.lstUsers;
        }

        private set
        {
            this.lstUsers= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LstUsers");
        }
    }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((o) =>
        {
            var result = getDataFromDatabase();
            UIThread((p) => LstUsers = result);
        }));
    }

    ObservableCollection<UserData> getDataFromDatabase()
    {            
        return this.RequestDataToDatabase();
    }

    static void UIThread(Action<object> a)
    {
        if(_dispatcher == null) _dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        //this is to make sure that the event is raised on the correct Thread
        _dispatcher.Invoke(a); <---- HERE EXCEPTION IS THROWN
    }
}
```

but in line _dispatcher.Invoke(a) an exception is thrown:

```
TargetParameterCountException: the parameter count mismatch
```

UserData is my data model, it is a class with some public properties. Something like:

```
public class UserData
{
   public string ID{ get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Surname { get; set; }

   // Other properties
}
```

so the problem is that the call to database is returning "RequestDataToDatabase" is returning a collection of UserData (ObservableCollection) so the exception is thrown.

I do not know how to solve it. Could you help me, please?

**Final solution**:

As XAMIMAX said in the comments:

- Change the signature from static void UIThread(Action a) to static void UIThread(Action a)
- modify UIThread((p) => LstUsers = result); by UIThread(() => LstUsers
  = result);

Comment: You say MvvM but not once have you mentioned a `ViewModel`. And if this is MvvM despite lack of View Model you could use [`Async Binding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn605875.aspx).

Comment: *"... in its constructor I have a call to a database"* that's not the MVVM way.

Comment: @Filburt sorry, I mean, constructor of viewmodel.

Comment: @Filburt I have edited the post. I mean constructor from viewmodel.

Comment: In you View Model call `ThreadPool.QueueUserTaskItem()` method and then use a `dispatcher` to make the data from the db Thread Safe. So your INPC can notify the view about the change.

Comment: Change the signature from `static void UIThread(Action<object> a)` to `static void UIThread(Action a)`. This will allow the method to be executed as it expects a parameter.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Now working, also need to modify UIThread((p) => LstUsers = result); by UIThread(() => LstUsers = result); One thing more, after LstUsers = result is set, I also need to set a property of the view model at the completion of the item added to the thread pool, so If I set the property value in the same point I set LstUser I get an exception TargetInvocationException because the subprocess that is calling it cannot access to this property because it is not the owner who created it.

Comment: Can you post the code for setting the property in your post?

Comment: @XAMlMAX Better to post another question and there I will explain it in details. I will be back and post here in the comments the link.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Below the link of the new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45300061/mvvm-upate-views-control-visibility-after-completion-of-threadpool-worker-item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of the possible solutions for you.
In your View Model you would have something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace VM
{
    public class TestViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private static Dispatcher _dispatcher;
        List<object> ListToDisplay { get; set; }//INPC omitted for brevity
        public TestViewModel()
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((o) =>
            {
                var result = getDataFromDatabase();
                UIThread(() => ListToDisplay = result);
            }));
        }

        List<object> getDataFromDatabase()
        {
            //your logic here
            return new List<object>();
        }

        static void UIThread(Action a)
        {
            if(_dispatcher == null) _dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
            //this is to make sure that the event is raised on the correct Thread
            _dispatcher.Invoke(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented your solution, but I get an exception: TargetParameterCountException: the parameter count mismatch. See my post updated. The problem is that the method that return info from the database is returning a collection of UserData. Could you tell me how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

As you can't await asynchronous methods in a constructor in C# 7.0 (but async Main is coming in 7.1) you can extract your async function calls to a separate function in your ViewModel and synchronously call this within your View's code-behind constructor, after you have created your ViewModel and assigned it to the View's DataContext:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.vm = new MyViewModel();
    this.DataContext = this.vm;
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.vm.AsychronousFunctionToCallDatabase();
}
```

As XAMIMAX says, you want to implement a ViewModel to handle business logic between your View and your models. Then if your ViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged and and you set up Binding in your XAML to your properties in the ViewModel - then the display will refresh after the database call without blocking the UI thread. Note, if you have any collections populated from the database call then they should be of type ObservableCollection.

But as Kundan says, in your AsychronousFunctionToCallDatabase() function you should include an await statement or a create a Task on the line that calls the database - this will return control to the calling function (in this case, to the MainWindow constructor).

Comment: In Net 3.5 there is no support for Task.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of options to run the method asynchronously.

- async await - https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx
- Task Parallel Library :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming