# MVVM: Update view's control visibility after completion of threadpool worker item in WPF NET 3.5

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, threadpool

I have a WPF MVVM app under NET 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008. Some controls in the view are bound to properties on the view model, so when these properties changes it will be notified to the view through the implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged.

I have some kind of splash saying "Loading..." that appears in the center of the window at the beginning, and it keeps visible while some data is being requested from database. Once data is requested from database, I want to hide this splash.

This splash is bound to a propert, "IsSplashVisible" in view model so updating the property to true, notify the splash to be shown at the beginnig and setting it to false, notify the splash to be hidden.

Setting property "IsSplashVisible" to true at the beginning there is no problem, the problem appears when setting the property to false once queued work item finishes. Once set this property to false, control (splash "Loading...") is notified and it tries to hide but fails as this is a different thread that the one who created it so the typical exception is thrown. So how can I solve this?

Below the code.

**View model**:

```
public class TestViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private static Dispatcher _dispatcher;
    public ObservableCollection<UserData> lstUsers

    public ObservableCollection<UserData> LstUsers
    {
        get
        {
            return this.lstUsers;
        }

        private set
        {
            this.lstUsers= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LstUsers");
        }
    }

    private bool isSplashVisible = false;

    public bool IsSplashVisible 
    {
            get
            {
                return this.isSplashVisible;
            }

            set
            {
                if (this.isSplashVisible== value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                this.isSplashVisible= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSplashVisible");
            }
    }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        this.IsSplashVisible = true;

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((o) =>
        {
            var result = getDataFromDatabase();
            UIThread(() => 
            {
               LstUsers = result;
               this.IsSplashVisible = false; <---- HERE IT FAILS
            });            
        }));
    }

    ObservableCollection<UserData> getDataFromDatabase()
    {            
        return this.RequestDataToDatabase();
    }

    static void UIThread(Action a)
    {
        if(_dispatcher == null) _dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        //this is to make sure that the event is raised on the correct Thread
        _dispatcher.Invoke(a); <---- HERE EXCEPTION IS THROWN
    }
}
```

Comment: Like @Clemens said, to incorporate this in your code put `Application.Current.Dispatcher`, so it looks like this `if(_dispatcher == null) _dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;`

Comment: @XAMlMAX Except that it doesn't make much sense to have the field at all. *Better* simply always call `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(...)`.

Comment: And while it may be quite far-fetched, you could theoretically have two view model instances created in two different UI threads. A static Dispatcher field wouldn't work well then.

Comment: @Clemens Only reason for this field is simplicity from my experience. I find it easier to type in `UI...` rather than `App...`->`Cu...`->`Disp`->`Inv...`->`(...` if that makes sense. BTW that piece of code was from a previous question that I have answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.currentdispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) is not the Dispatcher of the UI thread, because it

> Gets the Dispatcher for the thread currently executing and creates a new Dispatcher if one is not already associated with the thread.

You should use the Dispatcher of the current Application instance:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
{
    var result = getDataFromDatabase();

    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
    {
        LstUsers = result;
        IsSplashVisible = false;
    });            
});
```

---

Assuming that your TestViewModel constructor is called in the UI thread, you could have written it like shown below, where `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` is called in the UI thread instead of a ThreadPool thread. However, the field is entirely redundant. You could always just call `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke()`.

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    private readonly Dispatcher _dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        IsSplashVisible = true;

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
        {
            var result = getDataFromDatabase();

            _dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
            {
               LstUsers = result;
               IsSplashVisible = false;
            });            
        });
    }

    ...
}
```